# Optional parameters in HttpPost MVC marked as required?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, default-value

In my C# code, I have a method in my Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiController that gets values. However, if I call the GetThingsAsync method without having the Origin header set in the POST call, I get a 400 BadRequest error.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("route")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetThingsAsync(
            [FromBody] SomeRequest someRequest,
            [FromHeader(Name = "Origin")] string origin = "Unknown")
        {
            // Code goes here
        }
```

The error I get is like this:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "REDACTED",
    "errors":
    {
        "Origin":
        [
            "The origin field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, I assumed the code I'm writing should have a default value of Unknown if Origin isn't set. However, the origin value either isn't set properly, or the validation might be too zealous in some way. I'd like to know why I am getting an error when running this code without having the Origin header set in the request.

I understand that this problem can be fixed by adding a ? to the string argument like so:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("route")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetThingsAsync(
            [FromBody] SomeRequest someRequest,
            [FromHeader(Name = "Origin")] string? origin = "Unknown")
        {
            // Code goes here
        }
```

That being said, I want to know why this header is required even when it has a default value. Is it being set to null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that you use ASP.NET 6, It does not makes 400 error for other version.

As [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/nullable-reference-types#create-the-application-and-enable-nullable-reference-types) said:

> Beginning with .NET 6, new projects include the
> `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` element in the project file. Once the
> feature is turned on, existing reference variable declarations become
> **non-nullable reference types**.

So that the **non-nullable property** must be required in asp.net 6, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.

One way is to remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file.

Another way is to add `?` like below:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("route")]
public void GetThingsAsync(
    [FromBody] SomeRequestsomeRequest,
    [FromHeader(Name = "Origin")] string? origin = "Unknown")
{
    // Code goes here
}
```