# How to make a FromHeader parameter optional in minimal API

Tags: c#-6.0, minimal-apis

I have a minimal API working in C#6, but want to make one of the FromHeader parameters optional. This is the current code:

```
public static void MapGetInstallationByIngressEndpoint(this WebApplication app) =>
    app.MapPost(Url, async (
            [FromBody] GetInstallationByIngressRequest getInstallationByIngressRequest,
            [FromHeader(Name = Constants.AssetIdHeader)]
            Guid accountId,
            [FromHeader(Name = Constants.CorrIdHeader)]
            Guid correlationId,
            [FromServices] IRequestHandler<GetInstallationByIngressRequest, InstallationQueryResult> requestHandler,
            [FromServices] IValidator<GetInstallationByIngressRequest> requestValidator,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        {
```

and I want to make accountId optional. I've tried making it nullable (Guid? accountId), but no luck. Is it possible?

Comment: Making it nullable should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional parameters in HttpPost MVC marked as required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72538134/optional-parameters-in-httppost-mvc-marked-as-required)